# Try/catch block with a while statement, used to handle socket data, does not continue. No obvious errors (I think)

Tags: java, sockets, http

This is my main class - Main.java. Used to control requester but added for completeness.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import HtmlRequester.Requester;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Requester rq = new Requester("www.google.co.za", 80);

    try {
        rq.htmlRequest();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Connection failed.");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

}
}
```

This is requester.java, edited for shortness.

```
package HtmlRequester;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Requester{
    Socket httpSocket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    String server;
    int port;

public void setAttributes(String server, int port){
    this.server = server;
    this.port = port;
}

public String htmlRequest(String server, int port) throws IOException{
    try {
        httpSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(server), port);
        out = new PrintWriter(httpSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                httpSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + server);
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "
                           + "the connection to: " + server + "on port " + port);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    finally{
        System.out.println("Successful connection.");
    }

    out.println(compileRequestText());
    out.println("");

    String t;
    String ret = "";
    System.out.println("wait...");
    try {
        while((t = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
        ret.concat(t);
        System.out.println(t);
        }

        System.out.println("done");
    }
    catch(SocketException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Socket Exception :(");
    }
    System.out.println("Succesful data transfer.");

    out.close();
    in.close();
    httpSocket.close();
    return ret;
}

private String compileRequestText(){
    String ret = "GET / HTTP/1.1";

    return ret;
}
}
```

What happens is that the second try-catch block in Request.java, the block that contains:

```
while((t = in.readLine()) != null)
```

Will execute, and the response from server is successfully displayed. However, after the response is displayed, the loop will stop executing, the code does not move ahead to the finally block. The program does not seem to continue after that while loop. Anyone have any idea why?

i.e., 
            System.out.println("done");
is never reached, with no exceptions or compiler errors being thrown.

Comment: You haven't defined a finally-block in you second try-block. and it is good practice to place the close() in that finally-block. Also try using one try-block instead of two with al the code inside and the errorhandling at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is incomplete: you should add the `Connection: close` header, and also the `Host` header. See for example http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#http1.1clients

What is happening is that the server is leaving the connection open so you can send more requests through it, and the loop stays trying to read the results. This header disabled the behavior by asking the server to close the connection.

Closing the output stream to the server after sending the request probably works, too.

Comment: Hey thanks, that seems to have solved it. Another question, though, what should I use to seperate lines as well as finish the HTTP request? System.lineSeperator() doesn't seem to work, neither does \r\n.

Comment: Each header line should end with \r\n and the request with \r\n\r\n

Answer (score 1):

The server keeps the connection open to allow the client to send further requests. The client should determine the end of the current response not by detecting that the stream has been closed but rather by the "Content-Length" header sent in the response.

Here's how your loop can be rewritten to allow it to extract that length value:

```
  InputStream in = httpSocket.getInputStream();
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  boolean content = false;
  for (int i = 0; true; ++i) {
    if (content && i >= len)
      break;

    int ch = in.read();
    if(ch < 0)
      break;

    sb.append((char) ch);
    if (ch == '\n') {
      String s = sb.toString();
      if (!content && s.trim().isEmpty()) {
        content = true;
        i = 0;
      }
      if (len < 0)
        len = extractLength(s);

      System.out.print(s);
      sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
  }

  System.out.println(sb.toString());
  System.out.println("done");
```

This relies on these two auxiliary definitions:

```
private static final String HEADER = "Content-Length: ";

private int extractLength(String s) {
  if (!s.startsWith(HEADER))
    return -1;
  return Integer.parseInt(s.substring(HEADER.length()).trim());
}
```